# Any algorithmic models of our solar system to predict positions relative to earth?

Tags: solar-system, ephemeris, prediction

I'm looking for a map/model of the movements of our solar system and associated moons.

What are the 'best' algorythmic models to represent our solar system. Looking to write a game/edutainment app for users to find solar system objects.

I'm sure there is something out there, keywords googlefu fail ATM.

Comment: The word "ephemeris" (plural: ephemerides) is what you are missing. We have several questions on planetary ephemerides at this site already.

Comment: To start, search this site for the keywords "Spice", "Horizons", "Skyfield" and "PyEphem", and also search Astronomy Stack Exchange for the same. Since you know Python, [Skyfield](http://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) will give you the apparent position of the planets, Sun, Moon, stars seen from Earth (or any other place in the Solar System) in about 20 lines of script. Slightly related: [How to pronounce “Ephemerides”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/370655/217285)

Comment: If you got planet positions relative to the Sun, only a coordinate transformation is necessary to get the positions relative to Earth